# Recover a Visual Studio project that was never saved

Tags: visual-studio

I started a new project this morning and, after putting ~3 hours of work into it, I tried to open a file from another project to get some code from it. I got a warning about discarding an unsaved object. After telling it to go ahead, I realized that it was referring to the project I had just been working on and not another file that I had just opened.

Even though I never saved the project, the various files containing my code and dataset had to exist on the hard-drive. Are they still there, perhaps in a temp folder? I'm developing on a box running Server 2008 R2 (don't ask, not my decision :) ).

Comment: Hard lesson to learn--save and save often.

Comment: I learned the hard way. Its an unconscious action now. Ctrl-S. I do it after just about every line without even noticing. I do it in my sleep. :-)

Comment: @Russ: I thought I had already learned that one...I guess not :-(

Comment: @Russ just hitting ctrl-s wasn't sufficient(save document versus project).  I had just finished a prototype and was exiting VS2010 and didn't realize it was asking me if I wanted to save/discard a project and thought it was confirm some minor edits (that weren't intended).  For me, the real answer is below, force projects to be saved when created.  It would have been nice to have a recovery option...

Comment: I too Ctrl+S when I sleep but that is not enough in the case that you have "Save new projects when created" unchecked, in that case you need to save all (Ctrl+Shift+s), where you will get the Save Project dialog.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This may help:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2008/02/14/did-you-know-where-visual-studio-saves-auto-recovered-files-in-the-case-of-an-unexpected-shutdown-151.aspx

Also check C:\Users{Username}\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects

You could try one of those undelete programs and see if it finds anything.

Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions

and check the item

Save new projects when created

Save frequently. :)

Comment: I didn't get my work back, but I thought this was worth marking as the answer because of the suggestions.

Comment: Thanks, sorry you didn't manage to get it back. At least with the save new projects when created enabled it'll have backup files and autosave enabled.

Comment: Thanks! I found the project in the Temporary Projects Folder after my computer crashed before I saved the solution.

Comment: That saved my day, I was about to complete an order an VS crushed. I lost my project

Answer (score 8):

Need to give one related input. Who the hell had the idea to implement this feature???

I used Visual Studio until 2003, then came back again to 2010 now.
After 2 days work, **saving all the time**, as I used to (<kbd>Ctrl + S</kbd>), I close the project and decide **not to save the solution itself**.

Done. All lost. Nothing can be recovered from anywhere in the computer.

How can a developer implement a dumb idea such as dropping all work in an "in memory" project.
You either know about it already or you will get screwed; like thousands found on Google during my desperate search.

Did Microsoft VS team look at it at least?
So frustrating...

Answer (score 5):

It might be worth checking out **the folder where AutoRecover files are saved.**

You can find the default file location in Visual Studio on the Tools - Options menu. Look in the Projects and Solutions section - expand that and look in General to find the default file locations.

My files were under `C:\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Backup Files.`

Comment: Thank you. It worked on VS 2017. I found the modified files

Answer (score 5):

I had this happen to me this morning.  I worked on a new project yesterday and windows ran an update last night.  Despite having debugged my program - the project had not saved - for some reason it didn't occur to me that the project might not be saved.  I left the program running on my computer when I went to bed.  This morning when I work up, I saw that windows had run an update.  A few hours later, I saw that my computer had no trace of my program.  I realize this is an old post, but I thought I would shed some light on what I did, since i was able to recover my files.

First I went here:  http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/recover-lost-or-deleted-files

In Visual Basic 2010 Express, a backup folder is created with your project name.  Sure enough, my project backckup folder was there: Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Backup Files\MyProject.  But, the folder was empty.  I "restored this folder to a previous version" using the steps listed in the link above.  After doing that, the folder was still empty, BUT, the temporary folder "C:\Users{Username}\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects" now contained my project's folder and files.  Prior to running the "restore to previous version", the temporary projects folder was also empty.

So, I was able to copy the folder out of the Temporary Projects folder and I am as happy as one can be - or close to it.

Hope that helps someone out.

Comment: Found my lost project by going to "C:\Users{Username}\AppData\Local", right clicking on the Local folder, clicking on "Restore previous versions," selecting the appropriate version, and clicking the "Open" button.

Comment: I did the above but my project folder in the Temporary Projects folder was still empty.  I then restored previous version on the Temporary Projects folder and it recreated my project in the Temporary Projects folder...just letting everyone know there is another step if your project folder is empty...and this was a project that was gone almost a month.  Thank you so much for this.  Saved me hours of work!

Answer (score 0):

A note to the answers above, I had a mini jumpscare when i could not find my project anywhere, not in the recent projects nor in the visual studio projects folder.

I eventually found the project in the visual studio projects folder of the admin user;

I was looking at:

```
C:\Users\LocalUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects
```

Whilst the project was saved under:

```
C:\Users\LocalAdmin\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects
```

Bottom line is; also check the \documents of the admin user. This likely happend because i was testing an admin only application and visual studio was running with the admin's user profile loaded.