# Visual Studio 2013 Missing file after reopen visual studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, recovery

i working with visual studio 2013 and i save my project in Portable Hard Disk(it working normal previously) but at the night after i reopen my project solution it become error because some file missing(All files last working). i check in my obj folder. it still have form what i already make it before. so how to i restore this file? For note, it working with two difference PC(Day/Night).

Image :[Folder obj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVj1P.png)   ,  [Visual Studio Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hR3Tv.png)

Comment: check if frm_product_find and frmproduct exists first?

Comment: not exist..that why it become error..but why this file all missing?

Comment: worth try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533431/recover-a-project-that-was-never-saved

Comment: i check hold project are corrupted